# How to get entire file size when fuse write

Tags: fuse

I'm developing a file system based on fuse.
but experiencing difficulties during development.

My question is 'how to get entire file size when fuse_write'.

in fuse_write,

```
static int test_fuse_write(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size,
          off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
```

these arguments are not related to source file. only related to destination file.
I want a total file size.

for example, when copying file 'A' in ext4 file system to file 'B' in fuse file system. if size of file 'A' is 12MB, when the fuse_write function first called, is there a way to know the file size(12MB)?

I'm sorry I do not have enough English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Regardless of fuse file system, *write* is a file system operation while "copy" is a user utility (ex. *cp* in Unix). The copy utility executes *read* operations on the source file and *write* operations on the destination file. The *read*s and *write*s are "unaware" of each other. You can dig in the [source code of *cp*](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cp.c)

More ever, any *read* and *write* operations done by a user utility are divided by the kernel into consequent chunks of usually same size (ex. 64K). So a write operation of data in length of a few megabytes will be seen in your implementation of the fuse write function as a series of (let's say) 64K length consequent calls.

You should be encouraged that this is exactly the type of enlightenment you reach when writing a fuse file system...